# LSTM: adding the encoder's hidden states to the decoder in order to increase performance

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to experiment with transferring the hidden states of an LSTM from an encoder layer to a decoder layer, as demonstrated in the [Keras blog](https://blog.keras.io/a-ten-minute-introduction-to-sequence-to-sequence-learning-in-keras.html).

My data is randomly generated sine-waves (that is, wavelength and phase are determined randomly, as well as the length of the sequence), and the network is trained to receive a number of sine-waves and predict their progression.

Without transferring the hidden states, my code is as follows:

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, LSTM, Dense, TimeDistributed,Lambda, Dropout, Activation ,RepeatVector
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint 
import numpy as np

features_num=5 

encoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None, features_num))
encoder = LSTM(40, return_state=False)
encoder_outputs= encoder(encoder_inputs)


decoder_input=RepeatVector(150)(encoder_outputs)

decoder_lstm = LSTM(40, return_sequences=True, return_state=True)
decoder_outputs,_,_=decoder_lstm(decoder_input)
decoder_outputs=TimeDistributed(Dense(features_num))(decoder_outputs)


model = Model(encoder_inputs, decoder_outputs)


print(model.summary())

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')

def create_wavelength(min_wavelength, max_wavelength, fluxes_in_wavelength, category )  :         
#category :: 0 - train ; 2 - validate ; 4- test. 1;3;5 - dead space
    c=(category+np.random.random())/6         
    k = fluxes_in_wavelength
#
    base= (np.trunc(k*np.random.random()*(max_wavelength-min_wavelength))       +k*min_wavelength)  /k
    answer=base+c/k
    return (answer)       

def make_line(length,category):
    shift= np.random.random()
    wavelength = create_wavelength(30,10,1,category)
    a=np.arange(length)
    answer=np.sin(a/wavelength+shift)
    return answer




def make_data(seq_num,seq_len,dim,category):
    data=np.array([]).reshape(0,seq_len,dim)
    for i in range (seq_num):
        mini_data=np.array([]).reshape(0,seq_len)
        for j in range (dim):
            line = make_line(seq_len,category)
            line=line.reshape(1,seq_len)            
            mini_data=np.append(mini_data,line,axis=0)
        mini_data=np.swapaxes(mini_data,1,0)
        mini_data=mini_data.reshape(1,seq_len,dim)      
        data=np.append(data,mini_data,axis=0)
    return (data)



def train_generator():
    while True:
        sequence_length = np.random.randint(150, 300)+150       
        data=make_data(1000,sequence_length,features_num,0) # category=0 in train
        x_train = data[:,:-150,:] # all but last 150        
        y_train = (data[:, -150:, :]) # last 150        
        yield x_train, y_train
def val_generator():
    while True:
        sequence_length = np.random.randint(150, 300)+150       
        data=make_data(1000,sequence_length,features_num,2) # category=2 in val
        x_val = data[:,:-150,:] # all but last 150      
        y_val = (data[:, -150:, :]) # last 150      
        yield x_val, y_val
def test_maker():
    if True:
        sequence_length = np.random.randint(150, 300)+150       
        data=make_data(1000,sequence_length,features_num,4) # category=4 in test
        x_test = data[:,:-150,:] # all but last 150         
        y_test = (data[:, -150:, :]) # last 150     
        return x_test, y_test


filepath_for_w= 'flux_vi_model.h5'  
checkpointer=ModelCheckpoint(filepath_for_w, monitor='val_loss', verbose=0, save_best_only=True, mode='auto', period=1)     
model.fit_generator(train_generator(),callbacks=[checkpointer], steps_per_epoch=30, epochs=1000, verbose=1,validation_data=val_generator(),validation_steps=30)
model.save('filepath_for_w')

x,y= test_maker()   


a=model.predict (x)
np.save ('a.npy',a)
np.save ('y.npy',y)
np.save ('x.npy',x)
print (np.mean(np.absolute(y-a)))
```

The result is the distance between the actual 150 points of the sine-wave vs. the predicted values.

For this code, I received a result of 0.065.

When I tried to make use of the hidden states of the LSTM, my results, to my surprise, have worsened. I use the same code, replacing the model with:

```
encoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None, features_num))
encoder = LSTM(40, return_state=True)
encoder_outputs, state_h, state_c = encoder(encoder_inputs)
encoder_states = [state_h, state_c]

decoder_input=RepeatVector(150)(encoder_outputs)

decoder_lstm = LSTM(40, return_sequences=True, return_state=True)
decoder_outputs,_,_=decoder_lstm(decoder_input, initial_state=encoder_states)
decoder_outputs=TimeDistributed(Dense(features_num))(decoder_outputs)
```

The result was 0.101, indicting a reduced ability to predict the continuation of the sine-wave when having access to the hidden states of the encoder.

Is my approach wrong in this case and the hidden states cannot be used to improve prediction? Or did I construct the model incorrectly?

Comment: Can you please refer to the paper/report that shows that this method of taking the hidden states from encoder to decoder works (improves anything)? As far as I know, there is a weight tying method where the decoder weights is the transpose of the encoder (in dense layers, there are more adaptation when gating using LSTMs). This is used for regularization and indeed reported to be improving results in NLP problems. Usually used in the embedding layers.

Comment: I am not familiar with a work using this in the context of predicting sine-waves ( a toy problem, to be sure), but in the link I provided this methodology is used to connect the encoder LSTM to the decoder LSTM in a machine translation context.

https://blog.keras.io/a-ten-minute-introduction-to-sequence-to-sequence-learning-in-keras.html