# Make pre element inside td scrollable

Tags: html, css

I have a `pre` element inside `td` element (cell of html table). The table should use all space of a parent element, maintaining the same witdh for all it's columns, without any cell or table itself overflowing out of the space.

Without the `pre` element, it will work as described without any additional css. But with the `pre` element, the cell which contains it is extended to fit the content of the pre element: 50/50 share of columns there is no longer enforced, the whole table no longer fits into the screen and the whole page is now scrollable.

I would like to solve this by having a scrollbar for the `pre` elements only, so that any content inside it would not extend the table out of screen.

I tried to use `overflow-x` for this:

```
pre {
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```

but it has no effect.

Here is a minimal example:

```css
pre {
  overflow-x: auto;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
    
<colgroup>
<col width="50%">
<col width="50%">
</colgroup>
    
<td>
<p>Enim mollitia nostrum ut consequatur omnis neque. Esse itaque incidunt magni voluptas tempore aut quia.</p>
</td>
    
<td>
<pre>
curl --fail-early -I https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50782030/lstm-adding-the-encoders-hidden-states-to-the-decoder-in-order-to-increase-per
</pre>
<p>Enim mollitia nostrum ut consequatur omnis neque. Esse itaque incidunt magni voluptas tempore aut quia.</p>
</td>
    
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `table-layout: fixed` with `width: 100%` on `table` element and then also set `overflow-x: auto` on `pre` element.

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
pre {
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <colgroup>
    <col width="50%">
    <col width="50%">
  </colgroup>
  <td>
    <p>Enim mollitia nostrum ut consequatur omnis neque. Esse itaque incidunt magni voluptas tempore aut quia.</p>
  </td>
  <td>
    <pre>
curl --fail-early -I https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50782030/lstm-adding-the-encoders-hidden-states-to-the-decoder-in-order-to-increase-per
</pre>
    <p>Enim mollitia nostrum ut consequatur omnis neque. Esse itaque incidunt magni voluptas tempore aut quia.</p>
  </td>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you, using `width: 100%; table-layout: fixed;` for `table` elements does exactly what I need.

Comment: I'm using it with `overflow-x: auto;` for `pre` instead of `td` as you do in the example (as I prefer scrolling just this content, not the whole cell) and it works on firefox 60.